# AES Encrypt in Objective-C and decrypt in ColdFusion

Tags: objective-c, coldfusion, aes, encryption

In the first place I would like to thank you all for the help I have received reading this website. Thank you very much.

**The problem I'm facing is that I have to encrypt strings using objective-c (Iphone) and decrypt them using ColdFusion in a web server.** The algorithm I would like to use is AES-128.

At the moment, I managed to encrypt/decrypt in both sites but separately. All I am encrypting in objective-c can be decrypted in objective-c but not in ColdFusion. Basically, **the result of the encryption is not the same.**

I have code as simple and clean as I could to post it here.

My objective-c output is this one:

> Encrypted data: BHmXSHXWOH6McXsttNTgpL5EQmfPCebjVShkZOeHBC8=

My ColdFusion output is this one:

> Encrypted data: G+tdEOfQTtVCQGxW3N5uzlu0mGabRKNxuIdAXArQE80=

As you can see they are different :(
I think that the problem could be in the Objective-C code because the ColdFusion one is pretty simple. But I'm a bit lost right now, honestly. Any help would be very appreciated.

---

Here is a copy of the code I'm using:

**Objective-C code:**

```
// Starting point of the application.
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    NSString *strData = @"This is a plain string.";
    NSString *strKey = @"12345678123456781234567812345678";
    NSString *strIv = @"1234567812345678";

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:[strData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSData *iv = [NSData dataWithData:[strIv dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSData *key = [NSData dataWithData:[strKey dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSData *encryptedData = [self doCipher:data iv:iv key:key context:kCCEncrypt];
    NSLog(@"Encrypted data: %@",[self base64forData:encryptedData]);
}

// Method to encrypt/decrypt data
- (NSData *)doCipher:(NSData *)dataIn
                  iv:(NSData *)iv
                 key:(NSData *)symmetricKey
             context:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt
{
    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus   = kCCSuccess;
    size_t          cryptBytes = 0;    // Number of bytes moved to buffer.
    NSMutableData  *dataOut    = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:dataIn.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];

    ccStatus = CCCrypt( encryptOrDecrypt,
                       kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                       kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                       symmetricKey.bytes, 
                       kCCKeySizeAES128,
                       iv.bytes,
                       dataIn.bytes,
                       dataIn.length,
                       dataOut.mutableBytes,
                       dataOut.length,
                       &cryptBytes);

    if (ccStatus != kCCSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"CCCrypt status: %d", ccStatus);
    }

    dataOut.length = cryptBytes;

    return dataOut;
}

// Method to base64 encode data
- (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData {

    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [theData length];

    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        NSInteger j;
        for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }

        NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

**ColdFusion code.** I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301041/php-coldfusion9-aes-encryption-different-results):

```
<cfcontent type="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<cfset thePlainData = "This is a plain string." />
<cfset theKey = toBase64("12345678123456781234567812345678") />
<cfset theAlgorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" />
<cfset theEncoding = "base64" />
<cfset theIV = "1234567812345678" />

<cfset encryptedString = encrypt(thePlainData, theKey, theAlgorithm, theEncoding, theIV) />

<cfoutput>Encrypted data: #encryptedString#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IF that is the actual key you used, it looks like it is the wrong size. It is for AES 256, not 128. This key produces the same results in CF:

```
   <cfset theKey = toBase64("1234567812345678")>
```

**Result:**

```
    BHmXSHXWOH6McXsttNTgpL5EQmfPCebjVShkZOeHBC8=
```

Comment: The key size was definitely the cause of the problem. Thank you very much, Leigh.