# php code decrypt the coldfusion encrypted string

Tags: php, encryption, coldfusion

we are trying to decrypt the coldfusion encrypted string with AES/OFB/Nopadding in PHP. However, we got think even worse, we try all the solution here but still cannot get it work.

here is the code from CF

```
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="Yes">
<!--- Set encoding --->
<cfset k_strCharset="UTF-8">
<cfcontent type="text/html; charset=#k_strCharset#">
<cfset setEncoding("URL", "#k_strCharset#")>
<cfset setEncoding("FORM", "#k_strCharset#")>

<!--- Get variables --->
<cfif IsDefined("FORM.K1")><cfset fv_strK1="#FORM.K1#"><cfelse><cfset fv_strK1=""></cfif><!--- xxx --->
<cfif IsDefined("FORM.S1")><cfset fv_strS1="#FORM.S1#"><cfelse><cfset fv_strS1=""></cfif>
<cfif IsDefined("FORM.S2")><cfset fv_strS2="#FORM.S2#"><cfelse><cfset fv_strS2=""></cfif>

<!--- Encrypt / Decrypt --->
<cfif fv_strK1 is "xxx">
    <cfif fv_strS1 is not "">
        <cfset fv_strS2 = Encrypt(fv_strS1, fv_strK1, "AES/OFB/NoPadding", "BASE64")>
    <cfelseif fv_strS2 is not "">
        <cfset fv_strS1 = Decrypt(fv_strS2, fv_strK1, "AES/OFB/NoPadding", "BASE64")>
    </cfif>
    <cfset fv_strS3 = "">
    <cfset fv_strS4 = "">
    <cfset fv_strS5 = "">
</cfif>

<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="No">
```

then we do php as

```
<?php 

$z  = "bf19zWnbPmJxOvzRuP85Bw=="; 
$encrypted_string="q2SYE7hWWltsBw5byuwl/IkGmOOm+94=";
$source_text = html_entity_decode(getDecrypt($encrypted_string, $z), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');


//echo trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_OFB));

echo "<br>" . $z . "<br>";

// echo trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, base64_decode($z), base64_decode($encrypted_string), MCRYPT_MODE_OFB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_OFB), MCRYPT_RAND)));



echo "\n\nPlain-Text:\n" . $source_text . "\n";



// Functions
function getDecrypt($str, $key) {
    return ofb_decrypt(base64_decode($str),$key);
}

function ofb_decrypt($str, $key, $iv = ' ' ) 
{
    if ($iv==' ' & strlen($str) < 16)
        return false;
    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, ' ' , MCRYPT_MODE_NOFB, ' ');

    //RECEOVER IV
    $iv_size = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td);
    if (empty($iv)) {
            $iv = substr($str,0,$iv_size);
            $str = substr($str,$iv_size);
    }

// initialize encryption
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);

// decrypt
$decrypted_string = mdecrypt_generic($td, $str);

// terminate decrtypion 
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
mcrypt_module_close($td);

return $decrypted_string;
}


?>
```

the $encrypted_string is created by using the CF script above.

then we got the result is �=�����@�&O%NSC��#�p�:�

much appreciate if someone can give me a hint with it.

thank you

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196846/un-encrypting-re-encrypting-a-coldfusion-encrypted-string-in-php?rq=1) and see if you can adapt it for your purposes.

Comment: My client is encrypting in CF with AES/OFB/nopadding, how should i work it out ? i have tried a lot of method and no luck. on the other hand, they are not using IV. /_\ .

much appreciated you can help.

thank you

Comment: Perhaps [this question will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257620/decrypt-aes-from-coldfusion-to-php).

Answer (score 0):

Im able to get "testing" (and some garbage) out of the string using the poorly documented 'ncfb' argument to mcrypt_decrypt (http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.constants.php). I think the garbage is related to the block size...some additional input examples would be helpful.

```
function decryptColdfusionString($key, $data)
{
    $retVal = mcrypt_decrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
        base64_decode($key),
        base64_decode($data),
        'ncfb',
        '0000000000000000'
    );

    return $retVal;
}

$key  = "bf19zWnbPmJxOvzRuP85Bw==";
$data = "q2SYE7hWWltsBw5byuwl/IkGmOOm+94=";

echo decryptColdfusionString($key, $data) . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

(I realize this is a couple years old, but in case anyone runs into the same problem ... )

OFB mode requires an IV. Although the ColdFusion code did not specify an IV *explicitly*, [one was still generated automatically and prepended to the result](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/strong-encryption-coldfusion-mx-7.html). That IV must be extracted properly when decrypting, or the result will be gibberish. 1. Decode the encrypted base64 string *first*. 2. Then extract the IV and data from the decoded value and decrypt as usual.

**PHP:**

```
$key = base64_decode("bf19zWnbPmJxOvzRuP85Bw==");
$encrypted="q2SYE7hWWltsBw5byuwl/IkGmOOm+94=";

$decoded = base64_decode($encrypted);
$ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_NOFB);
$iv = substr($decoded, 0, $ivSize);
$data = substr($decoded, $ivSize);

$text = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_NOFB, $iv);
```

**Result:**

```
testing
```